# Checkboxes are not the same height as input boxes - Bootstrap

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I want the checkboxes on the left side to be the same height as the text input boxes on the right.

[image: Not set to proper height]

HTML:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ls.name}}</h1>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for item in ls.item_set.all %}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    {% if item.complete == True %}
                        <input type="checkbox", value="clicked", name="c{{item.id}}" checked>
                    {% else %}
                        <input type="checkbox", value="clicked", name="c{{item.id}}">
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text", value="{{item.text}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button type="submit", name = "newItem", value="newItem" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <input type="text", name="new">
        </div>

        <button type="submit", name = "save", value="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give you check box class then in you linked css give checkbox height and width acc to your need

```
<div class="input-group-text">
                    {% if item.complete == True %}
                        <input class="check" type="checkbox", value="clicked", name="c{{item.id}}" checked>
                    {% else %}
                        <input class="check" type="checkbox", value="clicked", name="c{{item.id}}">
                    {% endif %}
```

then in your css

```
.check {
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Only thing was that I had to place it inside of my base.html which is a template that this file extends.